# How can I write XUnit tests for the main method in a program.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xunit, .net-7.0

[image]
I have got a requirement to write unit test for main method but i couldn't do it in normal way
I have tried to do that by using
[image]
but its failing or the process is not stopping . Is there any better approach to write unit test for main method

Comment: Please refer to [ask], which will tell you to _always post code as formatted text_ instead of images.

Comment: If you want to write unit tests you must have written testable code. Not every code is testable. Whoever made this requirement for that `Main` method ... maybe he is joking ...

Answer (score 1):

The code *as written* isn't testable as the method won't return unless the console receives a signal to terminate the app as part of `Run()` (also having it `private` over-complicates calling it - you should make it `public` or `internal` and access it with [`[InternalsVisibleTo("...")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute)). However, if you refactored it to pull out most of the implementation, you could call *that* method and have the `Main()` method call that.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

public static class Program
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplication app = Bootstrap(args);
        app.Run();
    }

    public static WebApplication Bootstrap(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = new WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Your code here

        WebApplication app = builder.Build();

        // Your other code here

        return app;
    }
}

public static class MyUnitTests
{
    [Fact]
    public static void TestSomething()
    {
        string[] args = Array.Empty<string>();

        WebApplication app = Program.Bootstrap(args);

        Assert.NotNull(app);
    }
}
```

You could then ignore the uncovered code of `Main()` (as it's trivial) with [`[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute)

This would then give you coverage of most of the method, but how *valuable* that is other than *"chasing code coverage"* is a different matter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I think it's not possible to mock the app.run() Isn't?

Comment: No it isn't - if you _really_ need to chase that 100% coverage, then I'd suggest looking into [Integration Tests with `WebApplicationFactory<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests).

Answer (score 0):

When implementing unit tests it is best practise to re=structure your code in ways to facilitate testing. This will include exposing methods that you want to be *testable* via public interfaces. This in turn will ensure that you only use publicly typed interfaces for the arguments and response types to your methods.

> It is not a common requirement to unit-test the *main* method, as this test is often better realised by simply running the application. In your case the `Main(string[])` method is a *void method* and as such does not return anything so you should use `BeginInvoke` instead of Invoke, and not try to *Assert* any criteria against the output.